# paypal api - create buyer account

Tags: api, paypal

I'm looking solution for such flow in PayPal API (REST API preffered):

1. create buyer account -> 2. store credit card in vault -> 3. pay with credit card token

In paypal rest api documentation I found solution for 2) and 3), but I'm not sure 1) is possible to do with API.

I read this question ([Create Account Paypal API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208934/create-account-paypal-api)). It is some direction to follow, but I preffer coherent way and looking for solution in range of new REST API. So I read about identity api (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#identity). Is it a good direction ?

thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rest API is not setup just yet for account creation. However, you can use Adaptive Payments API to create accounts. Here is the information directly from the PayPal Payments Developer Site:

> The Adaptive Accounts API gives merchants and developers the ability to build applications that create and manage PayPal accounts. Using the functionality in Adaptive Accounts, you can create PayPal accounts, add additional funding methods to existing accounts, and verify the status of PayPal accounts from within your applications.

The below link has sample code in it: 
[Adaptive Accounts Creation Overview](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-accounts/gs_AdaptiveAccounts/)

> **Operation**     **Description**
>    **CreateAccount**  Creates a PayPal account on behalf of a third party.
>   **AddBankAccount**  Sets up a bank account as a funding source for a PayPal account.
>   **AddPaymentCard**  Sets up a credit card as a funding sources for a PayPal account.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. Is this account created with adaptive payment api will work with REST API method to add credit card ?